# Processing segments of a URL on click with javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, url, pagination, segments

I am currently building an ajax pagination which loads the page number into the URL and allows for history. The pagination itself works and loads up the next items within the DOM. However, I have run into some issues which depend on the original URL. I am using expression engine which dynamically creates the links for pages and the pagination, which can either be with or without a trailing slash, for example;

```
www.mysite.com/category/entry/title
```

or

```
www.mysite.com/account/user/1/
```

The way I have the ajax pagination working is to add a '#' to the url before the last segment of the rendered pagination link which triggers the next page to load by ajax.

The pagination links are absolute paths, which I do not have control over. I have told the script to split the URL and add the '#' and last segment from the clicked link to the existing URL. This renders as;

```
www.mysite.com/account/user/1/#p10
```

and the ajax pagination works fine. However, if there is no trailing slash, it is rendered as;

```
www.mysite.com/category/entry/title#p10
```

which fails to load the correct page

I'm struggling to create a conditional which adds a '/' to the end of the original URL before the split link is added, if not already present.

As well as this, I have experimented with including '/#' within the code, but which then renders the link as;

```
www.mysite.com/#p10
```

Missing out the rest of the URL

Below is the snippet of javascript I am using

```
$(wrapper).on("click", options.link, function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var linkPath = $(this).attr('href').split("/").pop();
window.location = '#' + linkPath;
});
```

Comment: `window.location.hash` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Euh, not sure this is what you mean, but:

```
if (url.charAt(url.length - 1) !== '/') url += '/'
```

And you can get the full current url with `window.location.href`
WIndow.location is an object, so in these kind of situation always try updating the hash or href or querypart seperately for the cleanest results.

Comment: Thanks, yeah this is the kind of thing i've been trying to do, but i'm not sure where it fits in the flow and it seems to break the script stopping at prevent default with there being no action when clicking the pagination links.

Comment: Have you tried using `window.location.hash = '#' + linkPath` as gcampbell suggested? It would prevent ending up with `www.mysite.com/#p10`.

Comment: Thank's, though it didn't change anything.